# Проблема с отладкой Qt

Tags: qt, отладчик

При запуске отладчика вылетает [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Установил **Debugging Tools for Windows** для windows 8.1 - не помогло, та же самая ошибка. Может быть, новый отладчик нужно где-то явно указать?

Версия Qt: **5.11.2 (MSVC 2015, 32 бита)**

Answer (score 1):

Вы установили отладчик, но не выбрали его. По умолчанию используется GNU gdb, который бинарно не совместим с выхлопом MSVC.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перейдите в меню 'Инструменты->Параметры' и в комплектах выберите отладчик CDB, соответствующий экосистеме компилятора MSVC.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]